# JavaNativeFoundation.framework comes without major version in Azul and Liberica JDK – how can I tell Java to use it anyway?

Tags: java, macos, arm64, apple-m1, azul-zulu

I am trying to use a native library on an ARM based Mac, i.e. an M1 processor. There are several JVMs available for that architecture, for example Azul or Liberica. Both come with a `JavaNativeFoundation.framework` dynamic library, which is necessary to use any JNI code. However, the framework does not have a `Versions` folder that contains the major version of the framework (like `A`). Instead, the library is just contained in the top level folder:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/_CodeSignature
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/_CodeSignature/CodeResources
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/JavaNativeFoundation
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Resources
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Resources/Info.plist
```

Trying to run my program I get

```
[java] AquaNativeSupport: Unable to load library libvaqua.dylib: /private/var/folders/tg/06858t0j3w10js_5hb3k5frw0000gn/T/libvaqua4883847212092667097.dylib: dlopen(/private/var/folders/tg/06858t0j3w10js_5hb3k5frw0000gn/T/libvaqua4883847212092667097.dylib, 0x0001): Library not loaded: @rpath/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation
[java]   Referenced from: /private/var/folders/tg/06858t0j3w10js_5hb3k5frw0000gn/T/libvaqua4883847212092667097.dylib
[java]   Reason: tried: '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/./JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file),
 '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/../JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file),
 '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/./JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/JavaNativeFoundation' (no such file),
 '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/../lib/JavaNativeFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Java
```

It looks like the output is incomplete, but anyway: You can see that java is trying to load the framework from a `Versions/A/` subfolder of the framework, which does not exist anywhere.

If I create that subfolder and create a softlink to the existing binary `JavaNativeFoundation` in it, then the application loads the JNI code just fine.

Given that situation I have two questions:

1. Why are the Frameworks in both Azul/zulu and Liberica missing the Versions structure?
2. Is there a way to work around that problem by loading the Framework in a different way? Some "dontusemajorversion" flag?

Thank you for your help.